# Carousel which only works on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a carousel which only works on mobile. On larger screens there should be a pretty standard grid row.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
IMAGE
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
IMAGE
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
IMAGE
</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the images are becoming a slider with only one image showing at a time on mobile devices with res lower than 650px.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this codepen I made.
It chekcs the device width (in pixels) and if its lower than 650 then its a mobile, so it shows the carousel, else it shows normal images.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Carousel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



  <div class="containerDesktop">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7PXLPzcIydw/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="car1" style="width:100%;">
      <img src="https://www.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/body-image/public/1-corvette-stingray-c8-2019-fd-hr-hero-front_0.jpg?itok=SEYe_vLy" alt="car2" style="width:100%;">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5d09594a62bcb0c9752779d9/125:94/w_1994,h_1500,c_limit/Transpo_G70_TA-518126.jpg" alt="car3" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

<div class="containerMobile">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7PXLPzcIydw/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="car1" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/body-image/public/1-corvette-stingray-c8-2019-fd-hr-hero-front_0.jpg?itok=SEYe_vLy" alt="car2" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5d09594a62bcb0c9752779d9/125:94/w_1994,h_1500,c_limit/Transpo_G70_TA-518126.jpg" alt="car3" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 650px) { 
  .containerMobile {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) { 
  .containerDesktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[Mobile Carousel](https://codepen.io/Yuvix/pen/KKVpbdg)

Comment: this is actually quite great. do you know how to make the slider draggable?